# A nice mess of a socket

Tags: java, sockets, networking

My code regarding the socket is split over three classes, and I've been working on it (and learning the Socket Api) for a few hours now, I've got it down to only one bug left (that i can see). The message recived from the server will simply not print, but instead throw out this error.

> Exception in thread "Thread-14" java.lang.NullPointerException 
>   main.Listen.run(Listen.java:11)  java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Console Class

```
package main;

public class Console extends Handle {

    String nextl = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    String info = "[INFO] ";
    String ser = "[SERVER] ";
    String err = "[ERROR] ";
    String name = "[" + userName + "] ";

    public void log() {
        startupCon();
        Network network = new Network();
        int allgood = network.connect();
        if (allgood == 34) {
            Listen listen = new Listen();
            new Thread(listen).start();
        }
    }

    void startupCon() {

        System.out.println("===========");
        System.out.println("=+CONSOLE+=");
        System.out.println("===========" + nextl);
    }

    void networkCon(String net) {
        System.out.println(net);
    }

}
```

Network Class:

```
package main;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Network extends Console {

    int port = 7771;
    String host = "localhost";
    Socket client;

    OutputStream outToServer;
    DataOutputStream out;
    InputStream inFromServer;
    DataInputStream in;

    public int connect() {
        int getOpen = open();
        System.out.println(getOpen);
        int getStream = trans(getOpen);
        System.out.println(getStream);
        return getStream;
    }

    int open() {
        try {

            networkCon(info + "Attemping to connect to /" + host + ":" + port);
            client = new Socket(host, port);
            System.out.println(info + "Established connection with "
                    + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());
            return 42;
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
            networkCon(err + "Socket timed out!");
            return 9;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(err + "Could not connect to /" + host + ":"
                    + port);
            return 9;
        }
    }

    int trans(int hostup) {
        if (hostup == 42) {
            try {
                outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
                out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
                inFromServer = client.getInputStream();
                in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
                return 34;
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
                networkCon(err + "Socket timed out!");
                return 8;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(err + "Connection lost!");
                return 8;
            }
        }
        return 7;
    }

}
```

Listen Class(The Bane of my Existence)

```
package main;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Listen extends Network implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    networkCon(in.readUTF());
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
                    networkCon(err + "Socket timed out!");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(err + "Connection lost!");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I'm guessing that the Stream isn't getting set to variable "in" within the class Listen, but I've got no clue if that's the problem or how to fix it.

Comment: `in` is null in `Listen`, like you guessed. Note that the NullPointer comes with a line number.

Comment: Ah, ty, time to figure out how to fetch the value correctly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have nowhere called the method `connect()` of `Network` class.. That's why your `DataInputStream in` is never initialized.. it is always `null` in your program..

I Guess that you should define a constructor in `Listen` class where you call `connect` method of superclass `Network` as follows:

```
public Listen()
{
  connect();
}
```

Comment: @DrZarreh why ? how can you say that?Have you called it somewhere else? how many times you have constructed the object of Listen?